# Maximal order of an order-preserving map

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets

Let $X$ be a finite partially ordered set, let $f\colon X\to X$ be an order-preserving map [edit: meaning $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$], and let $x_0$ be an initial point. Define $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ for all $n$; then the sequence $(x_n)$ is ultimately periodic. What is its worst-case period? I.e. what are the minimal $k<\ell$ such that $x_k=x_\ell$?

With no order assumption, one could have $\ell=\#X$ since the map $f$ could cycle through all of $X$. I'm particularly interested in the case when $X$ is the family of subsets of a set $Y$, and $x_0$ is a small subset. Does there then exist a non-trivial bound, say polynomial in $\#Y$ and exponential in $\#x_0$?

Comment: Nice question. In the case you care about, when $X=2^{Y}$ is a Boolean lattice, maybe you can argue that the worst case would be if $f$ is a permutation on $Y$.

Comment: I can never remember whether "order-preserving" means $x\lt y\implies f(x)\lt f(y)$ or $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$, please remind me.

Comment: @SamHopkins So the answer would be related somehow to Landau's function?

Comment: @bof: Regarding Landau's function- well, sort of, except that if we want to keep track of $\#x_0$ we should only take the lcm of $\#x_0$ cycle sizes. Regarding $<$ vs. $\leq$, I think $\leq$ is the usual one for defining morphisms of posets.

Comment: @bof I would rather state it with $\le$ (for the application I have in mind), I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: @SamHopkins I have trouble understanding what kind of structure there is on order-preserving maps. As an example, map all subsets of size $<k$ to the empty set, all subsets of size $>k$ to $Y$, and permute arbitrarily the sets of size $k$. Here we're saved because either $\#x_0$ is large or it hits immediately $\emptyset$.

Comment: You can have the poset with no relations except things like $x\le x$ and $f$ maps everything around in a cycle.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I believe the OP understood this ("With no order assumption, one could have $\ell=\#X$ since the map $f$ could cycle through all of $X$."); thus the focus on the Boolean lattice case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment about a special case that I think gives a negative answer to the last question. Let $\varOmega$ be a set of size $n$ and let $B$ be the lattice of its subsets with the inclusion order.

Now let $\phi:\varOmega\to\varOmega$ be any function. For $X\subseteq\varOmega$, define $X^\phi=\lbrace \phi(x) \mid x\in X\rbrace$ (duplicates removed of course).

Now it is elementary that $f:B\to B$ by $X\mapsto X^\phi$ is order-preserving. The question is: what can be said about the eventual cycle length of the trajectory of an element of $B$?

Consider the case that $\phi$ is a permutation. Take $x_0\in B$ to have one element from each of the cycles of $\phi$. Then the trajectory of $x_0$ is a cycle of length equal to the order of $\phi$ (as an element of the symmetric group).

For example, if $n=2 + 3 + \cdots + p_k$ (sum of first $k$ primes) and $\phi$ has one cycle of each prime size, then $\#x_0=k$ and the length of the cycle is $N = 2\times3\times\cdots\times p_k$.

I understand that
$N = \exp\bigl((1 + o(1)) k \log k\bigr)$.
So $N$ is larger than exponential in $\# x_0$.

Also, $n\sim \frac12 k^2\log k$.  If I got the inversion right, $\# x_0=\Theta(\sqrt{n/\log n})$ and $N=\exp(\Theta(n^{1/2}\log n))$.

Comment: Nice, so this is basically using Landau's function as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks -- it shows that not much can be hoped for, even in that (presumably nicest) case. I'll accept it as a (negative) answer!